# Foreach and $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have:

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test[one][]" value="a"><input type="text" name="test[two][]"  value="a"> <br />
<input type="text" name="test[one][]" value="s"><input type="text" name="test[two][]"  value="s"><br />
<input type="text" name="test[one][]"  value="d"><input type="text" name="test[two][]"  value="d"><br />
<input type="text" name="test[one][]"  value="f"><input type="text" name="test[two][]"  value="f"><br />
<input type="text" name="test[one][]"  value="g"><input type="text" name="test[two][]"  value="g"><br />

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

In database are:

```
 Table:
 id | one | two
```

in PHP i would like make:

```
if($_POST){
   foreach($_POST['test'] as $post){
          $new = new Table();
          $new->setOne($post['one']);
          $new->setTwo($post['two']);
          $new->save(); 
   }
}
```

But this not working... I can't use POST for index 'one' and 'two' - i must use two loop foreach. Is possible to make with one foreach or foreach in foreach?

print_r($_POST) return me:

```
[test] => Array ( [one] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => s [2] => d [3] => f [4] => g ) [two] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => s [2] => d [3] => f [4] => g ) ) )
```

Comment: Print a `var_dump($_POST)` to screen, and everything will be clean.

Comment: if you set it up like this, get rid of the 'one' and 'two' stuff. Loop your $_POST and map according to odd and even numbers (indexes) in your $_POST array.

Comment: By the way, give your object a descriptive name (such as $table) instead of $new, this improves readability of your code. Also, `if ($_POST)` doesn't make sure all `$_POST` values you need are set, you should use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) instead. Finally, I don't know whether you wrote the Table class yourself, but `setOne` and `setTwo` look like setters, while they're actually methods that add items (right?). Maybe you should change the names to `addOne` and `addTwo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go this way:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  // now $_POST['test'] is array('one' => array(), 'two' => array()
  for ($i = 0, $c = count($_POST['test']['one']); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $new = new Table();
    $new->setOne($_POST['test']['one'][$i]);
    $new->setTwo($_POST['test']['two'][$i]);
    $new->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($_POST['test'])){ // also check that the user submitted an array
   foreach($_POST['test'] as $post){
          $new = new Table();
          foreach ($post['one'] as $item) { // $post['one'] and $post['two'] should have the same number of elements so looping through $post['one'] is sufficient to get entries for $post['two']
              $new->setOne($item);
              $new->setTwo($item);
              $new->save(); // each item is saved in the database now
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: i updated the code. since i don't have access to new Table() i could only assume. it's clear now that ->save() does the INSERTs in to your database.